# Can one feasibly sell an adult-content screenplay?

Tags: screenwriting, erotica

So I may have a few fairly high-quality very-adult screenplays lying around and I was just wondering if there was any hope of my profitting off them in some way? Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Question: Are you familiar with any existing adult movies as being high-quality and similar in nature to your own work? I don't know the field, but finding a point of comparison is usually a great first step.

Answer (score 2):

Eh, it's almost impossible to sell screenplays in general.  That you have a screenplay for a movie that would be R or NC-17 moves it from "almost" impossible to "very nearly" impossible.

You know how many movies were [released in 2013 with a NC-17 rating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_NC-17_rated_films)? Two, *[Blue Is The Warmest Color](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Is_the_Warmest_Colour)* and something called *[Lucky Bastard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucky_Bastard_%282013_film%29)*.

Which might not sound like much, but it's two more than have been released in 2014.

I suppose you could look at the adult industry, but honestly, I don't think they are paying a lot for screenplays.  How much would it cost them to hire something to type up `EXT DOORWAY  The deliveryman knocks on the door`?

That leaves indie films.  If you really believed in the quality of the screenplays, you could hunt around for a director who wanted to do them, but don't expect a lot of money up front.